# How to run a jsp program?

Tags: java, jsp

This is a simple jsp program.can anyone tell me the steps to run it?

```
<%-- 
Document   : helloworld
Created on : Dec 20, 2010, 10:20:48 PM
Author     : eswar
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p> Hi, <h3><%="Hello!" %></h3></p>
    <p>You successfully run a simple jsp program.</p>
    <p>Learn More concept about jsp.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Deploy it as a war file in tomcat/glassfish/jboss or any other container and access the jsp page.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/shorttutorials/run-your-first-jsp-program-in-apache-tomcat-server

Answer (score 6):

You need a JSP/Serlvet container that can server JSP pages for you. There a number of JSP/Servlet containers available and used but the most commonly used is [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/).

To setup Tomcat,

1. simply download it and extract it into any folder
2. Next, place your application inside the webapps folder
3. Start the server.
4. Open your browser and browse to URL `http://localhost:8080`, it should open the tomcat's default page
5. Package your application as war, and place it in the webapps folder of tomcat
6. Now Access the URL `http://localhost:8080/YourApplicatioContext/path/to/jspFile` and you will see your JSP file being compiled and served in the browser

Comment: It might be helpful to try an ide like eclipse and a server plugin .

Comment: No doubt about that @semisided1

Comment: you repeated steps #2 and #5

Answer (score 1):

**You need servlet container, connector component and the JSP engine to run JSP pages.**
*In case of tomcat, Catalina is actually the servlet container. Coyote is the connector that handles the requests and forwards them onto Catalina. Web Pages are then delivered dynamically through Jasper, the JSP engine.*

Answer (score 0):

you need to have jsp container to execute you jsp files. you can use Tomcat(has jsp container in it) to run your jsp.

Comment: @EelLee I feel my answer is more appropriate to the question and fit in one liner