# How can I run Jsp project without eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I have a JSP project.It was created using Eclipse.

Is it possible to run a Eclipse project(without Eclipse).
If yes, then how can I convert its folder structure. So I could run it on my Apache Tomcat Webserver(without IDE).

I downloaded this project from internet. It was created using Eclipse.
My system specification is

- J.D.K. 8
- Apache Tomcat 8.5

You can reproduce this problem by using

This J.S.P. project which I have dowloaded.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uZT2D0CljfnWWaC_fchFbgQcjCcKiUZI/view?usp=sharing

I have read following post:
[How to run a J.S.P. program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373223/how-to-run-a-jsp-program)

This post suggest that I should create a war file. But I could not find any tutorial to do it without eclipse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a jsp program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373223/how-to-run-a-jsp-program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat or any other server does not know (and is not supposed to know) which IDE was used to create the web project. If you have `.war` file, just deploy it in Tomcat and it will run without making any change.

The command to create a `.war` file is as follows:

```
jar -cvf abc.war *
```

where `abc` can be any name of your choice.

Copy your project folder to a new directory. Go to that directory using `cd` command and then use the command given above to generate the `.war` file.

Also check [How to deploy a war file in Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109112/how-to-deploy-a-war-file-in-tomcat-7) to understand how to deploy the `.war` file.

Comment: How can I create a war file for this project without eclipse? @Arvind Kumar Avinash

Comment: @Aman - I've posted an update for it.

Comment: I created onlinelibrary.war file. I pasted this file in my webapps directory of Tomcat tried to access it through http://localhost:8080/onlinelibrary. It says not found. @Arvind Kumar Avinash

Comment: Did you start Tomcat sever?

Comment: Yes I restarted my Apache Tomcat Webserver. localhost:8080 is working. But http://localhost:8080/onlinelibrary/ is not working.

Comment: Can you see the extracted folder there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210358/discussion-between-aman-and-arvind-kumar-avinash).

Answer (score 1):

To run your project with a webserver like Tomcat, you need to build it first then deploy it to the webserver.

From Eclipse right-click on the project then export as war.

then deploy this war file to Tomcat.

Comment: How can I create a war file for this project without eclipse? @Sherif Abdelkhaliq

Comment: you can just use ANT or maven from the command line to build a project.

Comment: if you build your project from eclipse as a .war file it will not be related to eclipse, you can deploy it to any webserver, these tools give you more ability to choose how to build a project for example if you want to exclude a certain folder from the result war file.